# Deleting zero edges from a graph causes bizarre behavior

Tags: graphs-and-networks, bugs, crash

**Bug introduced in 10.3.0 and fixed in 10.4.**

---

Consider the following (very simple) graph, with two vertices and one edge:

```
g = Graph[{1, 2}, {1 <-> 2}];
```

I can use `EdgeDelete` to remove the edge from this graph:

```
EdgeDelete[g, {1 <-> 2}] (* returns Graph[{1, 2}, {}] *)
```

But something bizarrre happens if I use `EdgeDelete` to *not* remove any edges from the graph:

```
EdgeDelete[g, {}] (* returns StandardForm *)
```

For some reason, *Mathematica* returns the symbol `StandardForm`! To be more precise, it returns some object that *appears* to be the symbol `StandardForm`. I say this because attempting to interact with it in any way hangs the kernel:

```
EdgeDelete[g, {}] // FullForm    (* evaluating any of these three lines *)
Print[EdgeDelete[g, {}]]         (* causes the kernel to hang *)
Evaluate[EdgeDelete[g, {}]]
```

What's going on here? I'm using *Mathematica* 10.3 on Windows 10.

Comment: This is a v10.3 regression. I've reported it to WRI as a bug (soon after v10.3 was released) under case number 3449282.

Comment: What happens when you evaluate `EdgeDelete[g, {}]` followed by evaluating `FullForm[Hold @@ %]`

Comment: @Coolwater After `In[391] := EdgeDelete[g, {}]`, evaluating `FullForm[Hold @@ %]` produces `Hold[391]`. For some reason, despite the *Mathematica* notebook displaying `Out[391] := StandardForm`, `Out[391]` remains undefined.

Comment: @kirma So, in 10.2 it worked? Can't check it myself as I have removed all minor versions to reclaim space on my HD. If so, could you make an appropriate header as described [here](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/1610/standard-header-for-bugs-tagged-posts-for-easy-searching)?

Comment: @xavier Thanks. Added the bug header.

Comment: What happens if you try something like `EdgeDelete[g,{1<->3}]`? (i.e. deleting an edge not present in the graph.) I am speculating as to whether it is a problem caused because there are no edges present to delete, or perhaps just because of the empty set as the second input. (I have 10.2 here so I can't check it out.)

Comment: @KellenMyers It just stays unevaluated, and *Mathematica* issues a warning `EdgeDelete::inv : The argument {1 <-> 3} in EdgeDelete[Graph[<2>, <1>], {1 <-> 3}] is not a valid edge.`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bug introduced in 10.3.0 and fixed in 10.4.

Comment: Why is it voted for deletion? This question is unlikely to have any other answer than one like this, so why leave it unanswered?